# What's the difference between can't and won't?

Tags: grammar, difference, auxiliary-verbs

> This **won't** happen again. I promise.

Vs

> It **can't** happen.

What does the change of the auxiliary verb mean?

Answer (score 2):

*Won't* implies either a pledge, as in your example (*I promise*), or a confident prediction, or a refusal:

> Abduction by Martians has dropped off since the 70s. I'm pretty sure it won't happen to you again.
>   No matter how much you offer I won't sell you my daughter.

*Can't* implies either an impossibility or a directive:

> I'm sorry Bobby made that rude gesture. It can't happen again, because we've cut off his hands.
>   Yesterday Cathy sold one customer another customer's umbrella. This can't happen again.

Comment: can't happen means "this mustn't happen again?"

Comment: @username901345 In the umbrella example, yes.

Comment: so it doesn't mean the impossibility of the event occurring again in the future.?

Comment: @username901345 Not in that case, no.

Comment: so no future connotation?

Comment: @username901345 The reference in this case **is** to the future, but it does **not** say that it is impossible that the event should happen in the future: it says that the event must not be permitted to happen in the future.

Answer (score -1):

*Won't* implies that you are personally involved in preventing it recurring.

> It won't happen again, I'll personally make sure it doesn't.

*Can't* implies that someone else, or something else, is responsible for preventing it recurring.

> It can't happen again. They've changed their procedures.